# R - week function returns unexpected values

Tags: r, calendar, week-number, lubridate

I am looking to find the week within a year in R for a list of dates.  However, The outputs are rather weird.

See below:

```
week("2000-01-01")
week("2000-01-06")
week("2000-01-07")
week("2000-01-13")
week("2000-01-14")
```

This returns 1, 1, 2, 2, 3

However, if you look at a calendar:    http://calendars.generalblue.com/content/images/calendars/2000/01-January-2000-Calendar.png

You'd expect it to be 1, 2, 2, 3, 3.

For some reason, this rolls over on a Thursday.   Isn't that strange?

Does anyone know how I should do this to get the expected 1, 2, 2, 3, 3 results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at `?week`

> Weeks is the number of complete seven day periods that have occured
>   between the date and January 1st, plus one. isoweek returns the week
>   as it would appear in the ISO 8601 system, which uses a reoccuring
>   leap week.

Using the function isoweek you get the following result.

```
require(lubridate)
dates <- c("2000-01-01","2000-01-06","2000-01-07","2000-01-13","2000-01-14") 
sapply(dates, isoweek) 
2000-01-01 2000-01-06 2000-01-07 2000-01-13 2000-01-14 
        52          1          1          2          2
```

So when does a week "start" for you? In the following date-function a week start's on Sunday

```
require(lubridate)
my_week <- function(x){
  # fst monday of the same year
  first_sun <- as.POSIXct(paste0(year(x),"-01-Mon"), format = "%Y-%U-%a")
  (yday(x) + (7 - yday(first_sun) + 1)) %/% 7
}

dates <- seq(as.Date("2000-01-01"), as.Date("2000-01-15"), by=1)
a <- sapply(dates, my_week)
names(a) <- dates

> a
2000-01-01 2000-01-02 2000-01-03 2000-01-04 2000-01-05 
         0          1          1          1          1          
2000-01-06 2000-01-07 2000-01-08 2000-01-09 2000-01-10 
         1          1          1          2          2    
2000-01-11 2000-01-12 2000-01-13 2000-01-14 2000-01-15 
         2          2          2          2          2
```

Comment: that...is really annoying...Thank you!