# How to find week of month and year from datetime in r script

Tags: r, datetime

How can i find week_of_month and week_of_year from datetime in R script ?

Example: for datetime `2016-09-27 00:00:07.477`, `week_of_month is 5` and `week_of_year is 39`

I am getting `day_of month` from `weekdays.Date("2016-09-27 00:00:07.477")`.

Likewise i want to get `week_of_month` and `week_of_year`.

Comment: Have you read this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27116645/r-week-function-returns-unexpected-values and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25199851/r-how-to-get-the-week-number-of-the-month

Comment: Got solution from this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/25202142/1448357 for `week_of_month. and formatting date by `%U` gives week_of_year.

Answer (score 6):

You can do most of that with base R:

```
R> dt <- as.POSIXct("2016-09-27 00:00:07.477")   ## ISO8601 parsing
R> dt
[1] "2016-09-27 00:00:07.476 CDT"
R> plt <- as.POSIXlt(dt)
R> plt$mday                           # day of the month
[1] 27
R> plt$yday                           # day of the year
[1] 270
R> plt$wday                           # day of the week
[1] 2
R>
```

For some you need to look at `help(strptime)`

```
R> format(plt, "%U")                  # week of the year
[1] "39"
R> 
R> format(plt, "%V")                  # alternate definition
[1] "39"
R>
```

Comment: it gives `week of the year`. what for `week of the month` ?

Comment: Maybe `plt$mday %/% 7` ? You may need an offset or adjustment for common rules regarding the start of the week.